# Learner weighted sampling overweighting learners only at the school level

Tags: r, dplyr, random, statistics, sampling

I have a population level data set of 12m learners.

I am trying to sample at the school level as I do not have the compute for 12m learners.

I need to maintain whole schools in order to subsequently calculate school level stats, such as the fraction of female learners in the school.

If I simple random sample, small schools will be over represented at the learner level.

I want the average school size(`learner_count`), at the learner level, to be within sampling error of the population school size at the learner level. However, my code is returning data where the learner-weighted sampled **school-level** school size is the same as population **learner-level** school size but the sample **learner-level** school size is much much higher than than the population **learner-level** school size. I have tried creating school size weights (learners at school/all learners) as the weight in the sample function, but that returns the same result.

I am using the following code to sample:

```
#Create school level data
  unique_schools <- all_learners %>%
    filter(!is.na(school_id),
           !is.na(learner_count))%>% 
    group_by(school_id) %>% 
    summarise(school_id = first(school_id),
              learner_count = first(learner_count)) 
#%>% 
# mutate(learners_tot =  sum(learners_master, na.rm = T),
#     learner_weight = learner_count/learners_tot) %>% 
# select(school_id, learner_weight)

# Randomly select 1000 schools
  selected_schools <- unique_schools %>%
    sample_n(1000, weight = learner_count, replace = FALSE) #or weight = learner_weight

# Create the `sample` column and filter the dataset
  sample <- all_learners %>%
    mutate(sample = if_else(school_id %in% selected_schools$school_id, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(sample == 1)
```

Comment: Is `replace = FALSE` appropriate here? Let's take an extreme example where I have 9 schools with 1 student each and 1 school with 991 students. If I sample 5 schools without replacement, weighted by size, I will almost certainly pick the big school and 4 of the small schools, when the big school is responsible for 99.1% of my students, not 20%.

Comment: Tempted to push back on "I do not have the compute for 12m learners." Have you looked at data.table, or wrappers like dtplyr? It can be much more performant on data with many groups (eg > 10k is my untested gut threshold) than `dplyr` is. You might also look at `duckdb`, `arrow`, and `collapse`, which offer high-performance calculations on datasets that can even be larger than your RAM. For example: https://bwlewis.github.io/duckdb_and_r/taxi/taxi.html

Comment: @jonSpring Thanks, replacement could be a problem, but I have 26K schools, so unlikely to be an issue. I have also tried collapse and use data.table etc to calculate population-level stats, but I am pretty new to R and find tidylog indispensable to prevent errors. But thank you kindly for your input.